# Accepted answer to question no longer shows green check mark + change in answer order

Tags: bug, answers

Yesterday, I am pretty sure I accepted an answer given by a poster named HLKEM to [this question here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/38910/improving-communication-with-international-coworkers-from-another-culture/38925#38925). However, just now I went back to add some relevant details, and the green checkmark signifying that the answer was chosen by me as been the best was no longer present. I am sure I did not remove it. The checkmark seen right now was placed there by myself prior to writing this.

Secondarily, the order of the answers seem to have been swapped. Although @Scaahu's answer has one more up vote (3) than HLKEM's(2), its been moved downwards in the answers listed. Usually, answers are rated in descending order by # of up-votes, no?

What could have happened?

Comment: [question timeline](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/38910/timeline) shows that there was only one accept. Your [reputation tab](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/30062/anthony?tab=reputation) seems to show the same (see +2 events from accepting)

Comment: @gnat Okay, but even so, why would the answer with the higher up votes be below the answer with the lesser up votes?

Comment: Every user can decide to sort answers by active/oldest/vote. I may not see them in the same order you do.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110465/165773

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything suspicious in the post history.  Is it possible that you mis-clicked or accidentally clicked again to unaccept it?

As for the sorting, the accepted answer is always shown first regardless of voting, *unless* it's a self-answer.  If you accept your own answer to your question it is sorted by votes.  You can use the controls on any question to sort answers by age, most-recently active, or score; the default is score.